# mod_rewrite maximum number of internal redirects reached

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

My site worked fine until yesterday.

I got Apache 500 Internal Server Error: mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.

Probably the problem lies in the file .htaccess.

Full .htaccess [there](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzUIHK8ZnpSock1zU19fTHh0OUk/edit?usp=sharing)

May someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your 2 `.gz` rules as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css$ $1\.css\.gz [L]

# Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js$ $1\.js\.gz [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. I applied your corrections, restart webserver but it's still the same..

Comment: Haven't. Only one is in the root folder.

Comment: In that case best option is to enable `RewriteLog` via Apache config and then see which rule/code is misbehaving.

Comment: Done, [there](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzUIHK8ZnpSodkMwUUs1Z0tTU0k/edit?usp=sharing) is rewrite_log. 
Contained within the code is repeated several times. I do not know where the reference to that folder. Configuration files does not contain..

Comment: You have some rule with `'(^|/)\.'` pattern also. Can you post your latest .htaccess in your question for investigation.

Comment: Forgot to say: I mean folder "joom", when talk: "I do not know where the reference to that folder. Configuration files does not contain.." [htaccess file there](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzUIHK8ZnpSoSm9zcFR1N1UwRFE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Problem was in file virtual.conf.auto.. Hosting automatically set wrong path into DocumentRoot. =\ Thanks anyway for your attention to my problem =)